# Drupal "Joomla" Module batch issue

Tags: php, drupal, joomla, drupal-7, batch-processing

I installed lately Joomla module on Drupal 7 to migrate from joomla to drupal cms, the problem is that I have about 8000 article on joomla, so it's a massive migration, I'm always getting into timeout problem and can't get this to be done. I configured the batch in the Import settings and increased the delay to 10 and rows to 100. But still same problem, I looked into the joomla.module and found this function:

```
function joomla_sleep($row_number) {
  if ($row_number % variable_get('joomla_delay_row', JOOMLA_DELAY_ROW) == 0 ) {
    sleep(variable_get('joomla_delay_sec', JOOMLA_DELAY_SEC));
  }

}
```

I don't see whats wrong here, is it the problem from the module or the settings I configured? Plz help! If there's a way to implement a better batch api plz explain it a little bit because I'm new to drupal and didn't understand to integrate the Batch API on the website in the module I have.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either need to change settings in your php.ini file or decrease your batch size below 100.

Can you set the batch size to something much lower, like 5 and see if it times out?

Then gradually increase it until you find the threshold at what point your server can't handle doing.

Comment: I changed the " Number of imported rows before delay  " to 10 and " Delay before process next batch records (in second)  " to 5, but didn't work at all. Any idea? or a custom batch script that may use batch api to read from sql?

Comment: Is the script trying to migrate all of the articles in one shot or is it broken by into smaller cron tasks?